# Non-unital module over a ring with identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Is there a nontrivial example of a non-unital module over a ring with identity?  By trivial, I mean modules  with $rm = 0$ for all $r$ and $m$.

Just an idle question.  (Why is there no tag for that?)

Comment: what do you mean by non-unital module?

Comment: One that does not satisfy the axiom $1m = m$  for all $m$ in the module.

Comment: @Stephen I've answered your question below by explaining the underlying principle behind it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $M$ denote the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ considered as an $A$-module with the scalar multiplication map $A\times M\to M$ defined by
$$(a,(m_1,m_2))\mapsto (am_1,0).$$
This is a non-trivial $A$-module structure, and it is non-unital because multiplication by $1\in A$ is not the identity map on $M$.

Answer (score 19):

In essence there is no counterexample because of the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Every (not necessarily unital) module is a direct sum of a unital module and a trivial module.

*Proof:* Let $V$ be the module. Then we claim that $V=1_AV\oplus \operatorname{ker}\lambda_{1_A}$, where  $\lambda_{1_A}$ is left multiplication with $1_A$. Indeed let $v$ be in their intersection, then $v=1_Aw$ and $0=1_Av=1_A^2w=1_Aw=v$, hence the intersection is zero and furthermore $v=1_Av+(v-1_Av)$ with the former summand belonging to $1_AV$, the latter to $\operatorname{ker}\lambda_{1_A}$.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just like to add to Zev's excellent counterexample:

If $M$ is an abelian group, then $\text{End}(M)$ denotes the set of endomorphisms of $M$. (An **endomorphism** of the abelian group $M$ is a group homomorphism $M\to M$.) In fact, $\text{End}(M)$ is a ring under the operations of pointwise summation (addition in the ring) and function composition (multiplication in the ring).

***Exercise 1***: Prove that $\text{End}(M)$ is a ring if $M$ is an abelian group. (Check the ring axioms!)

Now, specifying an $R$-module $M$ is equivalent to specifying a ring homomorphism $R\to \text{End}(M)$. How so? Well, if we have an $R$-module $M$, then we just map $r\to \phi_r$ where $\phi_r:M\to M$ is defined by the rule $\phi_r(m)=rm$ for $m\in M$. Thus, we have a map $R\to \text{End}(M)$.

***Exercise 2***: If $M$ is an $R$-module, then check that this is a ring homomorphism $R\to \text{End}(M)$. Check also that specifying such a ring homomorphism is equivalent to specifying an $R$-module $M$.

Now, to say that $M$ is a **unital $R$-module** is to say that this ring homomorphism $R\to \text{End}(M)$ is unital; i.e., the unity of $R$ is mapped to the unity of $\text{End}(M)$. (The unity of $\text{End}(M)$ is just the identity homomorphism $M\to M$ in case you didn't do ***Exercise 1***. If this isn't obvious, then I suggest you do ***Exercise 1***!)

***Exercise 3***: Prove that every ring is isomorphic to $\text{End}(M)$ for some abelian group $M$.

This is the analogue of Cayley's theorem in ring theory and is the converse of ***Exercise 1***. (You might draw inspiration from the proof of Cayley's theorem in solving ***Exercise 3***.) So, in fact, finding the example you seek is equivalent to finding a ring homomorphism $R\to S$ that doesn't take the unity of $R$ to the unity of $S$. I.e., finding a non-unital ring homomorphism $R\to S$ of rings. That's what Zev has done. But thinking about the problem in this way makes it quite easy to construct counterexamples. What are examples of non-unital ring homomorphisms of which you know? I know a few, e.g.,

***Exercise 4***: Prove that $\mathbb{R}\to M_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by the rule $x\to \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is a non-unital ring homomorphism.

Can you find others?

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When R-Module is not an unital module (that is 1.m is not equal to m or m.1 is not equal to m) then we can have pathologies such as rm=0 for all r belongs to R and m belongs to M.
Some books use only Unital modules as an exercise to avoid such pathologies. It's not necessary for the module that R (ring) is commutative or with unity. But if R has unity then it is an unital module otherwise Non-Unital module. And if it is commutative then the Left module will be equal to the right module (rm=mr for all r belongs to R and m belongs to M). Otherwise, it is non-commutative.